# HTML5 Video as web page background

Tags: html, video, background

I currently have a video loop as my web page background either calling a mp4 or a ogg or a webm video file depending on with browser the viewer has. In chrome and IE , the video starts immediately using the mp4 file, yet in firefox, the ogg or the webm video file is taking about 10 seconds to load. Yet, the ogg and webm files are half the size as the mp4. Why is firefox loading the first frame and waiting to load before playing? Seems strange that it would not start immediately especially since it's half the size of the mp4?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution from HTML5Doctor:

> Usually HTML5 audio and video players will allow the user to start
>   playing a media file before it has fully downloaded (as long as it
>   actually has something to play!). Sometimes this isn’t the case with
>   an MP4 file, where the browser waits to download the entire file
>   before making it available to play. This is due to an encoding issue.
>
> Sometimes MP4 files are encoded with the file index (which contains
>   information on the file such as it’s duration) placed at the end of
>   the media file rather than at the beginning. This index contains the
>   metadata that the browser requires in order for it to offer
>   progressive download. If this index is at the end, it knows nothing at
>   all about the file and therefore has to wait until it receives the
>   index.
>
> If this happens to you, there’s a simple fix called the QTIndexSwapper
>   by Renaun Erickson that you download to your computer and run on the
>   file that simply moves the index to the start of the file and saves
>   it.